# Display value in table even query returns none

Tags: sql

I want to display value 0 if there is no counted rows in table book trx into my php/html table. But when I try to query in SQL, it only shows rows that have values in book trx.

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT book_class, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM `bk_trx` LEFT JOIN books ON bk_trx.`book_no_perolehan` = books.`book_no_perolehan` 
WHERE bk_trx.`dateout` LIKE '%2019%' 
AND `dateout` LIKE '01/%' 
AND bk_trx.`std_class` = '5' 
GROUP BY books.`book_class` , bk_trx.`std_class`
```

IN Book Trx Table

```
SELECT `trx_id`, `std_class`, `std_class_name`, `book_no_perolehan`, `dateout` 
FROM `bk_trx`
```

Data in book trx table:

```
trx_id,    std_class,  std_class_name,  book_no_perolehan,     dateout

1     ,    5        ,  H             ,  33481            ,     01/12/2019

2     ,    5        ,  B             ,  33491            ,     01/13/2019
```

IN Book Table

```
SELECT `book_id`, `book_no_perolehan`, `book_class` 
FROM `books`
```

Data in book table:

```
book_id , book_no_perolehan , book_class

1       , 33481             , F

2       , 33491             , 800

3       , 33450             , FCL
```

After Query in SQL:

**Actual Table Result**

```
book class  , Total

800         , 1

50C         , 1
```

I want to display my result like this, if there is no rows for FCL in database, but it will shows value 0 in the table.

**Table Expected**

```
book class , Total  
800        ,  1  
FCL        ,  0  
50C        ,  1
```

Comment: Can you edit this post to format the code inside, it will make it a lot easier for us to understand what is sql vs what is true verbiage. To make a code block simply insert at least 4 spaces in front of the code and for indented lines beneath you can insert 4 more spaces.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will make it more understandable in future question! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to just use the `left join` correctly:

```
SELECT b.book_class, COUNT(t.book_no_perolehan) AS total 
FROM books b LEFT JOIN
     bk_trx t    
     ON t.`book_no_perolehan` = b.`book_no_perolehan` AND
        t.`dateout` >= '2019-01-01' AND t.dateout < '2020-02-01' AND
        t.`std_class` = '5' 
GROUP BY b.`book_class`;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly as expected now. I added a temporary table to store data to prevent slow query.